# "ERROR 000819: Tool is not assigned" While Running Spatial ETL Tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, spatial-etl, data-interoperability

I have Created a spatial ETL tool to do small operations like adding an ID, updating different fields, etc.

While running it from the Edit Session of Spatial ETL it runs well and good.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000003q000000

Now I want to run it from ArcCatalog without opening the tool, but it is throwing an error

[image]

and inside geoprocessing results it Shows

> ERROR 000819: THE TOOL IS NOT ASSIGNED

can anyone please help me with this, on how to run the tool without using the edit session.

One more question: Inside the properties of the tool, "Always run in Foreground" option is disabled, because of this I guess I have to disable background processing and run the tool in foreground. The help page " [Foreground and background processing"](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000003q000000) is also not solving the problem. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the toolbox to catalog before running it from the same instance in ArcMap maybe.
http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000013000819.htm

Comment: my tools are already in ArcCatlog inside the MyToolboxes Folder, and we want it to run directly from ArcCatlog, without programming, i have added new image in the question, please see that.

Comment: It worked, what i did is from ArcCatlog i opened ArcToolbox, there an option is present of adding a toolbox, select that, and browse to the path where the toolbox is present. After this the toolbox is added into the ArcToolbox, from where it executes properly. The Importing Toolbox helped me do that thank you @geoffreyWest

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when 64bit background processing is installed (up to at least ArcGIS 10.3.1) and a 64bit *"third-party Python module referenced in the toolbox is not installed ... When the Python toolbox tool is run, 64-bit background geoprocessing cannot access the module in the 32-bit Python folder. The toolbox appears to be valid with correct syntax because ArcGIS has access to the 32-bit modules, but does not check for the 64-bit modules."*

Solutions are:

- uninstall 64bit background processing
- identify the missing module and install it's 64bit version (if available)
- Edit the [Python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm)'s tools so they always run in the foreground by assigning the `self.canRunInBackground` line of code with `False`:

  ```
  class Tool(object):
      def __init__(self):
          """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
          self.label = "Tool"
          self.description = ""
          self.canRunInBackground = False
  ```

From Esri-KB 40933: http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40933. I couldn't find a current 10.3x version, not sure why.